# BeautifulSoup How to get text from <a> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i don't get how to extract text from this class

`<a href="/all/views/all/" class="cmc-link">7,457</a>`

i want to get `7,457` but i don't get it how... i tried this but its only showing me links

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
anchors = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'cmc-link', 'href': True})

for anchor in anchors:
    print (anchor['href'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('span:contains("Cryptocurrencies") a').text)
```

Prints:

```
7,457
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.text` property (Will return the innertext of the anchor or any other elements, where `['href']` will return the href attribute value):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
anchors = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'cmc-link', 'href': True})

for anchor in anchors:
    print(anchor.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `anchor['href']` will only `return` the `href` attribute of the `anchor tag`. Use `.text` in order to get the text. Here is how you do it:

```
print (anchor.text)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
anchors = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'cmc-link', 'href': True})

for anchor in anchors:
    print (anchor.text)
```